# Parsing six figure Ordnance Survey Grid Reference input

Tags: parsing

An extensive search has produced no answer to the question, "Is there a class or function that parses input for soundness relating to UK Ordnance Survey Grid References".
The UK is mapped by the UK Ordnance Survey who produce detailed maps of the United Kingdom with many types of referencing.  One of these is the commonly used six figure Grid Reference, we are at SO896804.
We already use a postcode (zip) checker to make sure that the information entered into the postcode field is sound, but we can't find the same for the OS Grid Reference.
Does such a Grid Reference function exist, or do we down tools and write one?
Thank you.

Comment: I'm going to go with "Huh??"  What exactly is your question, and what programming language are you using?

Comment: What do you consider "sound"? That the grid reference is syntactically valid? That it corresponds to some part of the territory of the United Kingdom (including coastal waters)? That there is actually some human construction somewhere in the 100m square?

Comment: I think you probably want to ask this question on http://gis.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

Since you tagged this "parsing", rather than using some GIS-like tag, I'd say that a reasonably valid OS grid reference corresponds to the regular expression:

```
(H[PTUWXYZ]|N[ABCDFGHJKLMNORQSTUWXYZ]|OV|S[CDEHJKMNOPRSTUVWXYZ]|T[AFGLMQRV])([0-9]{6})
```

If you were prepared to accept 4-digit 100ha blocks as well as the six-digit 1ha blocks, you could replace the second parenthesized expression with `([0-9]{4}|[0-9]{2})`.

Of course, some of the two-letter blocks are almost completely marine. You could almost certainly ignore [`OV`](http://www.geograph.org.uk/article/In-Search-of-OV0000), for example. `NW` contains a little bit of Dumfries & Galloway (Portpatrick, NW995545), and a much larger but irrelevant part of Northern Ireland.